# In virto Commerce, After changing the default theme site, what time these changes can be seen in storefront?

Tags: virtocommerce

In virto Commerce, After changing the default theme site, what time these changes can be seen in storefront?
I've changed the default theme in the admin panel, but in the storefront was seen as old themes. so I was forced to see the new changes, I reset application pool of storefront site.

I have the same problem in catalog module in  products part. I changed the default photo  of product and I would save it, but when I go to storefront, I do not see the change.sometimes in product page , i see the changes(but randomly(based on my observations)) . but in category product, I do not see the change.

how Cache information works in storefront?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storefront have 10 min default cache expiration time. 
We definetely will soon make manual cache reset function in manager. 
At current moment exist only one way to force cache invalidation - it work if you have installed manager and storefront on same Azure application. You may reset storefront cache by made any changes in cms theme files and it will cause cache invalidation.

Comment: thanks a lot, I realized, there is a section with name "cacheManager" in web.config of  storefront which can be changed at the time cache.